# LocalStorage with PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, mobile, cross-platform, local-storage

I am initializing my localStorage with body onload="init()" so it sets the value to localStorage. My problem is that the value is not returned to and represented inside a div i wish to.

I have debugged it and made sure it works.

So I am wondering what kind of lifecycle does PhoneGap follow? ie. when is the html loaded again? Every time user returns to the app or every time the app is actually not running on a device?

Answer (score 0):

You should use PhoneGap's onDeviceReady event for initializing your code. See the documentation [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready).